# Media gallery thumbnails stretched when image is horizontal ratio in magento 2.4.5-p2

Tags: thumbnail, gallery-image, magento2.4.5p1

I have a problem when the images are not square. I have already disabled all extensions and enabled the Luma theme. That doesn't fix the problem.
When I upload a non-square image, the preview looks like this.

[image]

Best regards  Straddi